# Unlist a list of dataframes

Tags: r

This is possibly a really simple question. I have a list of dataframes (df1, df2.... dfn), i.e. each element of the list is a dataframe. So basically, the list was created like this:

```
mylist = list(df1, df2,...., dfn)
```

But how do I do the reverse, that is unlist so that df1, df2, etc. reside separately in the workspace?

Comment: Thanks. Are you a telepath?

Comment: The question *should* be, why would you *want* to do this. If you have all your df's in a lovely list, there's hardly ever a reason you need to make them into separate objects. You can just work with them as elements of your list.

Comment: Agree with Simon. If you want to call them by name its better to name in them in the list - e.g. `myList = list(df1=data.frame(...), df2=data.frame(...), ...)` and call them with `myList[['df1']`

Comment: Just a matter of convenience, I guess. With RStudio, it's easier to keep track of all the dataframes.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use `list2env` it is specially designed for this:

> From a named list x, create an environment containing all list
>   components as objects, or “multi-assign” from x into a pre-existing
>   environment.

So here :

```
list2env(mylist ,.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: wow, you learn something every day!! This would've been great to know years ago! +1

Comment: This looks kinda dangerous!

Comment: @SimonWoodward yse it dangenrous in the global env but you can create an `env()` and list variables there.

Answer (score 20):

You could simply use a for-loop along with the `assign` function like that:

```
# Sample data
df.list <- list(data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c(10, 20, 30)), 
                data.frame(x = 4:6, y = c(40, 50, 60)), 
                data.frame(x = 7:9, y = c(70, 80, 90)))

# Write out single data frames
for (i in seq(df.list))
  assign(paste0("df", i), df.list[[i]])
```

Comment: awesome solution when you have a un-named list.

Comment: how can i write that into different dataframes?

Comment: @krushnachChandra It is written to different data.frames, in this case `df1,df2,df3`.