# Use a function to modify multiple dataframes

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a function to deduplicate a data frame so that each person (indexed by PatID) is represented once by the latest record (largest RecID):

```
dedupit <- function(x) {
        x <- x[order(x$PatID, -x$RecID),]
        x <- x[ !duplicated(x$PatID), ]
        return(x)
        }
```

It can deduplicate and replace a dataframe if I do:

```
df <- dedupit(df)
```

But I have multiple data frames that need deduplication.  Rather than write the above code for each individual data frame, I would like to apply a the dedupit function across multiple dataframes at once so that it replaces the unduplicated dataframe with the duplicated version.

I was able to make a list of the dataframes and lapply the function across each element in the list with:

```
listofdifs <- list(df1, df2, ....)
listofdfs <- lapply(trial, function(x) dedupit(x))
```

Though, it only modifies the elements of the list and does not replace the unduplicated dataframes.  How do I apply this function to modify and replace multiple dataframes?

Comment: This is the recommended way of handling multiple dataframes. Keeping them in a list is cleaner than filling your global environment with dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work? 
Name your dataframes when creating the list, so you can recover them afterwards

```
list.df <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)

list2env(lapply(list.df, dedupit), .GlobalEnv)
```

As a result your dataframes df1, df2, df3 will be the deduplicate version.

[unlist a list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697239/r-unlist-a-list-of-dataframes)