# mutate column for multiple dataframes from a list in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list of 12 data.frames:

```
m  =list(X2016_kvish_1_10t, X2015_kvish_1_10t, X2014_kvish_1_10t,
     X2013_kvish_1_10t, X2012_kvish_1_10t, X2011_kvish_1_10t,
     X2010_kvish_1_10t, X2009_kvish_1_10t, X2008_kvish_1_10t)
     X2007_kvish_1_10t, X2006_kvish_1_10t, X2005_kvish_1_10t)
```

and I have a list of 12 vectors called `mean_values`. Output from `str(mean_values)`:

```
 List of 12
$ : Named num [1:168] 2848 2848 2848 2848 2848 ...
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:168] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
$ : Named num [1:168] 2870 2870 2870 2870 2870 ...
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:168] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
$ : Named num [1:168] 2911 2911 2911 2911 2911 ...
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:168] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
$ : Named num [1:168] 3422 3422 3422 3422 3422 ...
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:168] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
$ : NULL
$ : Named num [1:168] 2747 2747 2747 2747 2747 ...
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:168] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
$ : Named num [1:168] 3234 3234 3234 3234 3234 ...
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:168] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
$ : Named num [1:168] 3334 3334 3334 3334 3334 ...
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:168] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
$ : Named num [1:168] 3440 3440 3440 3440 3440 3440 3440 3440 3440 3440 ...
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:168] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
$ : Named num [1:168] 3327 3327 3327 3327 3327 ...
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:168] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
$ : Named num [1:168] 3440 3440 3440 3440 3440 ...
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:168] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
$ : Named num [1:168] 3497 3497 3497 3497 3497 ...
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:168] "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
```

I need to add each vector to new column in each data.frame from the list. when I do separately it works well:

```
X2016_kvish_1_10t$mean_values = mean_values[[1]]
X2016_kvish_1_10t$mean_values = mean_values[[2]]
X2016_kvish_1_10t$mean_values = mean_values[[3]]
# ... until 12
```

but I need to find a way to add these vectors in one shot.
I tried this function:

```
for(i in 1:length(m)){m[[i]]$means = mean_values[[i]]}
```

this function works great but only when I print the whole list of the dataframes. I need to find a way to apply the changes to the originals dateframes, each one s.

Comment: It's working as you expect it to. I just tried your code on sample data: `df1 <- data.frame(v1=c(1,2),v2=c(3,4)); 
df2 <- data.frame(v1=c(2,2),v2=c(3,2));
df3 <- data.frame(v1=c(1,1),v2=c(4,4));
m=list(df1,df2,df3);
mean_values <- list(c(5,5),c(6,6),c(7,7)); 
for(i in 1:length(m)){m[[i]]$means = mean_values[[i]]};
m`.

Comment: It works, but the changes doesn't appear to be in the original data.frames. how can apply this changes to the original data.frames ?

Comment: I personally would keep them in the list for convenience, but if you want them back out, try the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697239/unlist-a-list-of-dataframes)- try `list2env(m, .GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: I tried. but it shows me an error: `Error in list2env(m, .GlobalEnv) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x`

Comment: @MichaelSpector - Oh right- you created `m` as an unnamed list. If you do `m = list(X2016_kvish_1_10t = X2016_kvish_1_10t, X2015_kvish_1_10t = X2015_kvish_1_10t, ...)` it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! It works :)  I would have buy you a present but I guess you live in the other side of the world :)   see you tomorrow with my new questions   good night

Answer (score 0):

Despite not knowing why you would want to do that... I think I got what you want.

If the items of your list are named, you could try:

```
for(i in 1:length(m)){
    assign(names(m)[i], m[[i]])
}
```

If your list is not conveniently named, you may name it like this:
`names(m) <- ls()[grep(pattern = 'kvish', x = ls(), ignore.case = TRUE)]`

This will work if the dataframes of yours are the only objects in your memory that have `kvish` in their names.

But you have to be careful with the order of the names. Check the output of `ls()[grep(pattern = 'kvish', x = ls(), ignore.case = TRUE)]` and see if it's on the same order as your dataframes of the list.

Comment: I tried and it gives me an error: `Error in assign(names(m)[i], m[[i]]) : invalid first argument`

Comment: What is the output of `names(m)`?