# naming lists within for loop using paste0 and get/eval, parse

Tags: r, naming

Straight to the question.
[as1_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTMec.png)

I am trying to name data.frames in a list using name() and paste()
but I am having trouble assigning them

```
num_fu = c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
as <- data.frame()

for (i in num_fu){
           assign(paste0("flnames", i), list.files(path = paste0("C:/Users/thepr/Documents/data/as", i), pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE))
           assign(paste0("as", i, "_list"), lapply(get(paste0("flnames", i)),
                                          function(x){base::as.data.frame(read.csv(x))}))
           
           nm <- gsub(".csv", "", basename(get(paste0("flnames", i)))) %>% str_sub(., 1,6)
```

`nm` returns

> nm
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTMec.png) "as1_01" "as1_02" "as1_03" "as1_04" "as1_05" "as1_07" "as1_08" "as1_09" "as1_11" "as1_13"
> [11] "as1_14" "as1_15" "as1_99"

and

`names(as1_list)` returns

```
> names(as1_list)
NULL
```

I tried get(paste0 ...

```
names(get(paste0("as", i, "_list"))) <- nm
```

this returns error:
Error in names(get(paste0("as", i, "_list"))) <- nm :
target of assignment expands to non-language object

so I tried

```
names(eval(parse(text = paste0("as", i, "_list")))) <- nm
```

and this occurred:
Error in names(eval(parse(text = paste0("as", i, "_list")))) <- nm :
target of assignment expands to non-language object

I have also tried assign() function using both of the above codes.

```
assign(names(get(paste0("as", i, "_list"))), nm)
```

Returns:
Error in assign(names(get(paste0("as", i, "_list"))), nm) :
invalid first argument

and

```
assign(names(eval(parse(text = paste0("as", i, "_list")))), nm)
```

Returns:
Error in assign(names(eval(parse(text = paste0("as", i, "_list")))), nm) :
invalid first argument

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: and just typing ```as1_list <- nm``` works perfectly. but I want to do it using for loop or vectors since they are a cohort data with numerous follow-ups

Comment: What should the result look like? A list, where each item is a `read.csv`-generated dataframe, named according to the CSV source file? Do you want to row-bind the list items to one big dataframe later on?

Comment: @I_O yes exactly, except column-bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in your comment, the following will give you a list of dataframes, each from a single CSV-file (starting with "as") and named with the filename excluding extension:

```
data_dir <- 'C:/Users/thepr/Documents/data/'
file_names <- list.files(data_dir, pattern = 'as.*\\.csv')

list_of_dataframes <- 
  file_names |>
  Map(f = \(fn) read.csv(file.path(data_dir,fn))) |>
  setNames(nm = gsub('\\.csv', '', file_names))
```

Note the use of `Map` to operate on a list (of file names, in this case) and avoid any `for` loop (generally a good idea in R).

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. ```data_dir <- 'C:/Users/thepr/Documents/data/as'``` is the exact data_dir, and also I have  9 lists of dataframes. The example I posted is just as1_list. and I have upto as9_list. So there should be vectors within 9 vectors? I should have mentioned this in the post. That's why I first used for loop.

Comment: The above code does not work. ```list_of_dataframes, file_names``` returns 'named_list' and  'character(0)'

Answer (score 1):

I learned that it is mostly a bad idea to use `assign()` within `for` loops.

Just learn to use the vectorised nature of R to make it shine!

For example, consider storing the results of your `for` loop in a single list. You can still convert the list contents to single objects later on: [Unlist a list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697239/unlist-a-list-of-dataframes)

I think, what you are trying to accomplish is to batch read .csv-files and renaming them. Have a look here: [How to import multiple .csv files at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once)

Comment: I agree. Nothing seems to work here. I will try vectorizing them.